# How to make the variables inside an imported component's function to reflect to their present values rather than their initial values in angular8?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am declaring a private variable for the imported component in the constructor of the another component. Example

```
constructor( private x: Xcomponent){}
```

Then i call a function declared inside Xcomponent

```
 x.scanx()
```

Inside the scanx function there is a variable whose initial value was `ShouldChange=null;`  Before scanx was called its value was changed by another function inside Xcomponent as `ShouldChange ={ 'some':'something'} ;` Now when scanx is called from another component the value of ShouldChange is null. I have tried to access the values of variables declared and changed in class (Not component) and i get the present values not the initial ones as its happening when i try to access the values of imported components.

I am using visual code IDE. The language is typescript.

```
import { Xcomponent } from '../Xcomponent/xcomponent.component';
import { Globals } from '../globals';

export class parentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private x: Xcomponent, private global: Globals) {
    }

    runThisFunction() {
        x.scanx(global.theVariableRetainsEditedValue); // The variable in global instance retains the changed values.
    }
}

// Inside scanx function of Xcomponent
export class Xcomponent implements OnInit {
    ShouldChange = null;

    someotherFunction() {
        this.ShouldChange = {'some': 'somethingelse'}
    }

    ngOnInit() {
this.someotherFunction();
this.confirmTheChange();
    }

    confirmTheChange() {
        if (this.ShouldChange === null) {
            alert("This never happens");
        }
        else {
            alert("THE VALUE WAS INDEED CHANGED");
        }
    }

    scanx(SomeInput) {
        if (this.ShouldChange === null) {
            alert("This Should not happen");
        } else {
            alert("This is not happening. Why?");
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the value of the variable `ShouldChange` to not be null since its changed in ngOninit. But it reflects its initial value when called from an imported instance of the component. However checking the variable's value from the unimported instance  of the component shows that the value has indeed changed as shown in `confirmTheChange()` function.

Comment: in your `ngOnInit()` you need to use `this` or those functions won't be called. `this.someotherFunction();` and `this.confirmTheChange();`

Comment: I added ``` this. ``` to the ngOninit functions. But that is not my issue. My question is how do i access the present value of ``` ShouldChange ``` variable. Right now when i import the class and try to access the variable it gives me the initial value not the value that was given to it recently by another function which was called from the original class (not the imported instance of it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are not getting the new value because the function is not returning the new value ...

Well on the function that changed the y value, add a 
`return y` at the end as

```
scanx(){
*// the rest of the function that changed the code*
return y
}
```

and on the other component where you are calling `'scanx'`

```
runThisFunction() {
 const y = x.scanx(global.theVariableRetainsEditedValue); // The variable in global instance retains the changed values.
*y will hold the new value*
}
```

If this not work, using observables would be a good solution.
You create an observable in a service that will act as a data mediator between the two 
RxJS BehaviorSubject is a good option.

***Step one*** - create a new service and create a BehaviorSubject and create a method for changing the value of the observable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ValueChangerService {
  private initialValue = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  currentValue = this.initialValue.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeValue(value: number) {
    this.initialValue.next(value)
  }
}
```

***Step Two*** inject the service to your components and change the value in one component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValueChangerService } from './value-changer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private valueChanger: ValueChangerService) {
  }


  setValue(value) {
    this.valueChanger.changeValue(value);
  }
}
```

***Step Three*** Subscribe to it in the other component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValueChangerService } from "./value-changer.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
   Hello Component
   the value of y is {{y}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {

  y: number;

  constructor(private valueChanger: ValueChangerService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.valueChanger.currentValue.subscribe(value => this.y = value)
  }
}
```

you can find the full code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvh6xj

And Check out https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/  by Jeff Delaney !

Answer (score 0):

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3haxd)

> X Component

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {TestService} from "./test.service"

    @Component( {
      selector: 'x-child',
      template: ``,
    })
    export class XchildComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private valueChanger: TestService) { 

         this.valueChanger.currentValue.subscribe(value =>  
         this.ShouldChange = value
            )
      }

      ShouldChange = null;

        someotherFunction() {
          //  this.ShouldChange = {'some': 'somethingelse'}

             this.valueChanger.changeValue({'some': 'somethingelse'});
        }

        ngOnInit() {

          this.someotherFunction();
          this.confirmTheChange();
        }

        confirmTheChange() {
            if (this.ShouldChange === null) {
                alert("This never happens");
            }
            else {
                alert("THE VALUE WAS INDEED CHANGED");
            }
        }

        scanx(value: any) {
            if (this.ShouldChange === null) {
                alert("This Should not happen");
            } else {
                alert("This is not happening. Why?");
            }
        }
    }
```

> Parent component

```
import { XchildComponent } from './x-child.component'
import { Component , ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component( {
  selector: 'parent',
  template: ``,

})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
constructor(public child: XchildComponent) {

}


ngAfterViewInit() {

this.child.scanx('checking new value')
}


}
```

> Hope, this solves your problem